# Linux distribution popularity by location

Tags: linux

I was just wondering which GNU/Linux distribution is popular in which part of the world. I am not trying to start a distro war here, just curious to know if any statistics are available about the popularity of distributions based on location.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to answer this.

Comment: How is there no way to answer this? The OP is after links and references to demonstrate popularity. I can provide several such links to authorative sources for this.

Comment: I do not think this is subjective or argumentative. I just wanted to know if these statistics were available. For example we can use [Google Insights](http://www.google.com/insights/search/#) and get info regarding the search for some key words. I was just curious to know if someone has already made similar statistics. So if possible I would like to re-open this (as this was marked closed). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At my company, we use combinations of Redhat and OEL for production servers and Fedora and Ubuntu for development/user systems.  These are in a number of locations in US and in UK, India and Australia.

Comment: That's not so general answer in any way, unless your company is really huge.

Comment: This is not a good answer.